# What exactly is the role of the mysterious space underlying the definition of a superspace?

Tags: differential-geometry, supermanifolds, supergeometry

In the intro to chapter 12.3 of [this](https://books.google.de/books?hl=en&lr=&id=k7ThnAXz99gC&oi=fnd&pg=PR3&dq=Coherent+states+and+applications+in+mathematical+physics&ots=tTkcP8p6vx&sig=P0s1rNWO-7Aa3dOQjZAKgHQa0eU&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=Coherent%20states%20and%20applications%20in%20mathematical%20physics&f=false) book about the applications of coherent states, it says that
classical spaces for bosons are real or complex vector spaces or manifolds, whereas classical spaces for fermions are Grassmann algebras $\mathbb{K}[\theta_1, ... ,\theta_n], \mathbb{K}=\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$.
More precisely the classical space for fermions is given by the space of smooth
mappings $f$ from $B$, a certain set of dimension $0$, to the Grassmann
algebra $\mathbb{K}[\theta]$

$$
f: B \rightarrow \mathbb{K}[\theta]
$$

What exactly is the role of this ominous space $B$ in this definition? Why is it even needed, why can one not directly work with the Grassmann algebra for the fermionic part of superspace?

As an example, for a system with $n$ bosons and $m$ fermions (or $n$ bosonic and $m$
fermionic coordinates? The bosons and fermions should be obtained as the coefficients
when expanding a superfield in the Grassmann coordinates!) the configuration
space is called a superspace $\mathbb{R}^{n|m}$ and is defined as

$$C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^{n|m})
=C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^n)[\theta_1, ... ,\theta_n]
=C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^n)\otimes \mathcal G_m
$$
where $\mathcal G_m$ is the fermionic part parameterized by $n$ Grassmann variables $\theta_i$.

Does $\mathbb{R}^{n|m}$ here take the role of the space $B$ that was rather abstractly alluded to above?